# Inputting errors in structure pointer code

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, structure

```
 #include <stdio.h>
typedef struct book
{
    int bid;
    char bname[50];
} bok;
typedef struct student
{
    int roll;
    char sec;
    char name[50];
    bok *issue;
} stud;

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter no. of students\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    stud s[n];
    printf("enter names,section and roll no. of %d students\n", n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", &s[i].name);
        scanf("%c", &s[i].sec);
        scanf("%d", &s[i].roll);
    }
    int m, temp;
    printf("enter no. of books\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    bok s1[m];
    printf("enter book id and book names of %d books\n", m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\n", &s1[i].bid);
        scanf("%s\n", &s1[i].bname);
    }
    printf("assign book id to students.\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("assign id for roll %d\n", s[i].roll);
        scanf("%d\n", s[i].issue);
    }
    int info;
    printf("enter roll no. of student to get his/her information and book assigned to him\n ");
    scanf("%d\n", &info);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        if (s[i].sec == info)
            printf("name:%s \nsection:%c \nbook assigned:%s\n", s[i].name, s[i].sec, *s[i].issue);
    }
}
```

my code is not showing any compilation error but it does not give required output.my question is Create 2 two structure array Student and Book by the name S and B. And link the students with their respective books.
Print the books issued by a particular student.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget the brackets in order to assign user's input to the corresponding struct member:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    scanf("%s", &(s[i].name));
    scanf("%c", &(s[i].sec));
    scanf("%d", &(s[i].roll));
}
```

and here you need to assign the input to bid, you cannot set an integer for book:

```c
scanf("%d\n", &(s[i]->issue.bid));
```

or you wil get a segfault.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer antonin but it didnt worked:'(